# Selenium crashing and trying to troubleshoot

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver

I had a script that uses Selenium for web-scraping. It recently started failing.  I'm running it from a python script on Ubuntu.

Here's how I've set up the webdriver:

```
#set driver options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
chrome_options.binary_location='/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
chrome_driver_binary = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

And the web-scraper, basically just iterating through a bunch of URLs to grab data:

```
for i in range(1,10):

    time.sleep(1.5)

    #cycle through pages in range
    driver.get(base_url + str(i))
    pageURL = base_url + str(i)

    # get events links
    event_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class^=AtIvjk2YjzXSULT1cmVx] a[class^=HsqHp2xM2FkfSdjy1mlU]')
    # collect href attribute of events in even_list
    events.extend(list(event.get_attribute("href") for event in event_list))

print("total events: ", (len(events)))

#GET request user-agent
headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36"}


# iterate through all events and open them.
item = {}
allEvents = []
for event in events:

    driver.get(event)
    currentUrl = driver.current_url
```

Sometimes, the script works, other times it fails with this:

```
     File "/home/ubuntu/scraper/my_scraper.py", line 136, in <module>
    currentUrl = driver.current_url
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 669, in current_url
    return self.execute(Command.GET_CURRENT_URL)['value']
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
  (Session info: headless chrome=99.0.4844.51)
```

OK, so it seems it's failing on this line, or the line directly above it:

```
currentUrl = driver.current_url
```

As mentioned, it works sometimes, but other times fails.  I've tried:

- Updating Chromedriver/Chrome to same version on Ubuntu.
- Checked my instance disk space:  it's got 2.7G available.
- I've increased my instance size as well.

How else can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: you should probably remove this argument "--remote-debugging-port=9222".  Let Selenium choose the port.  (I think you'd set that if you were running the site from an IDE debugger... something like that where you need to attach to it.)  This probably has nothing to do with the exception though.  Sounds like Chrome is crashing... could be running out of memory... or taking up too much CPU.  I'd keep a resource monitor open while the script is running to check.

Comment: Also if the browser is still open after you receive this exception (check your processes), this may be due to a session timeout. So if a URL takes a very long time to load... like over 30 minutes, Selenium may kill the idle session and try to shut down the browser. The session will be killed but the browser will not shut down because it is still trying to load a page. This leaves both the driver and browser open but the driver can no longer communicate with the browser.

Comment: Might be related to [Issue 4048: target frame detached](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4048&q=cannot%20determine%20loading%20status%20from%20target%20frame%20detached&can=1)

Comment: We had issues similar to this, and rolled back to chrome 88. Then we determined it was resource related, and setup our own runners. Are you running this on your host? Or in docker? Are you able to add more memory and cpu cores and re-run?